# How to perform pairwise.t.test in nested data frame

Tags: r, purrr

I would like to perform pairwise.t.test in the nested data frame. Is it possible?

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
a <- mtcars%>%
  dplyr::select(disp, gear,am)%>%
  nest(-am)%>%
  mutate(t_test = map(data, ~ pairwise.t.test(disp, gear, p.adjust = "bonferroni")))

# Error in factor(g) : object 'gear' not found
```

Comment: I believe this is possible. Can you please show how you would do one of the t-tests manually without `purrr`, just so I can see output you are looking for? Then can you please specify what you want to iterate over?

Comment: Here how I would do the pairwise comparison of gear with 3 levels (3, 4, 5). But I would like to iterate over am. 

`mtcars_sub <- mtcars%>% dplyr::select(disp, gear,am) pairwise.t.test(mtcars_sub$disp, mtcars_sub$gear, p.adjust = "bonferroni" )` @JeremyK.

Answer (score 3):

You have to specify the data frames inside the nested column using `.x`.

```
a <- mtcars %>%
  select(disp, gear,am) %>%
  nest(data = c(-am)) %>%
  mutate(t_test = map(data, ~pairwise.t.test(.x$disp, .x$gear, p.adjust = "bonferroni")))
```

If you don't need the (nested) column `data` you can do it with just `group_by` and `summarise`

```
a <- mtcars %>%
  select(disp, gear,am) %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  summarise(t_test = list(pairwise.t.test(disp, gear, p.adjust = "bonferroni")))
```

In both cases, you can get the results into a table form using `broom` (i guess you wanted that since you load that package).

```
a %>% 
  mutate(t_test = map(t_test, broom::tidy)) %>% 
  unnest(t_test)
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks @Jan Kislinger

Answer (score 0):

Does this give the output you were looking for?

```
library(dplyr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars_sub <- mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::select(disp, gear, am) %>% 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  nest()  


t_tests <- function(df){
  pairwise.t.test(df$disp, df$gear, p.adjust = "bonferroni")
}

map(mtcars_sub$data, t_tests)

#> [[1]]
#> 
#>  Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 
#> 
#> data:  df$disp and df$gear 
#> 
#>   4    
#> 5 0.048
#> 
#> P value adjustment method: bonferroni 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#>  Pairwise comparisons using t tests with pooled SD 
#> 
#> data:  df$disp and df$gear 
#> 
#>   3     
#> 4 0.0027
#> 
#> P value adjustment method: bonferroni
```

Let me know if it's not the right output you need.

Credit to @ronak-shah

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62408521/8742237

Comment: Thanks. I found the solution of @Jan Kislinger easier to implement in a more complex data frame.