# How to reference a column in a nested dataframe (then use purrr::map)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have a very simple question about referencing data columns within a nested dataframe.

For a reproducible example, I'll nest `mtcars` by the two values of variable `am`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars_nested <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  nest()
mtcars_nested
```

which gives data that looks like this.

```
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#> # Groups:   am [2]
#>      am data              
#>   <dbl> <list>            
#> 1     1 <tibble [13 × 10]>
#> 2     0 <tibble [19 × 10]>
```

If I now wanted to use `purrr::map` to take the mean of `mpg` for each level of `am`

I wonder why this doesn't work:

```
take_mean_mpg <- function(df){
  mean(df[["data"]]$mpg)
}

map(mtcars_nested, take_mean_mpg)
```

```
Error in df[["data"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

Or maybe a simpler question is: How should I properly reference the `mpg` column, once it's nested. I know that this doesn't work:

```
mtcars_nested[["data"]]$mpg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dataframes (and tbls) are lists of columns, not lists of rows, so when you pass the whole tbl `mtcars_nest` to `map()` it is iterating over the columns not over the rows. You can use `mutate` with your function, and `map_dbl` so that your new columns is not a list column.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars_nested <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(am) %>% 
  nest()
mtcars_nested

take_mean_mpg <- function(df){
  mean(df$mpg)
}

mtcars_nested %>%
  mutate(mean_mpg = map_dbl(.data[["data"]], take_mean_mpg))
```

The `.data[["data"]]` argument to `map_dbl()` gives it the `data` list column from you dataframe to iterate over, rather than the entire dataframe. The `.data` part of the argument has no relation to your column named "data", it is the [rlang pronoun .data](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/tidyeval-data.html) to reference your whole dataframe. `[["data"]]` then retrieves the column named "data" from your dataframe. You use mutate because you are trying (I assumed, perhaps incorrectly) to add a column with the averages to the nested dataframe. `mutate()` is used to add columns, so you add a column equal to the output of `map()` (or `map_dbl()`) with your function, which will return the list (or vector) of averages.

This can me a confusing concept. Although `map()` is often used to iterate over the rows of a dataframe, it technically iterates over a list (see the [documentation](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html), where under the arguments it says:

> *.x*  A list or atomic vector.

It also returns a list or a vector. The good news is that columns are just lists of values, so you pass it the list (column) you want it to iterate over and assign it to the list (column) where you want it stored (this assignment happens with `mutate()`).

Comment: Your explanation of why my code didn't work is very helpful. Is it the `mutate` or the `map_dbl` that stops map from iterating over the columns and not the rows? Or what was it in your solution that made `map` iterate over rows? Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyK. good question, I have updated my answer to provide more clarity. In short, you iterate over the rows by passing the column "data' as the `.x` argument to `map()`, rather than passing your whole dataframe as the argument.

Comment: For anyone trying to solve a similar question, I really recommend reading the `rlang pronoun .data` link @wil provided, and the `map` documentation. @wil thank you for being so patient; I finally understand now.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass `mtcars_nested$data` in `map` and take mean of `mpg` column.

```
take_mean_mpg <- function(df){
     mean(df$mpg)
}

purrr::map(mtcars_nested$data, take_mean_mpg)
#[[1]]
#[1] 24.39231

#[[2]]
#[1] 17.14737
```